# Has anyone every had an issue with the Auto Number feature in Access where it duplicates?

Tags: properties

In my database we are using the auto number feature in a table as an auto generated serial number. I have run into several issues where we enter some records and is duplicating the numbers. It is a split database. Some of the entries into the table are individual and others are done through an append query and are added in batches of 35 to 145 at a time.

Comment: Moderators at strike https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an - so I also will not do **any** (further) content/curation-related action here